# Batch script to rename files in folder argument

Tags: batch-file

I can't find any references explaining how to loop through a folder passed as an argument and rename each file.  All examples I've seen assume the script is running in the folder where files will be renamed or hardcode the folder path in the loop.  How can I do this?  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
for /f %%a in (%1) do call :RenameFiles

:RenameFiles
Rename %%a "new filename"
Goto :EOF
```

Comment: If your goal is to rename many files in a folder, consider using Rename Master http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following adds prefix "renamed-" to every file in the directory specified as a command line argument:

```
for %%F in (%~1\*) do ren "%%~F" "renamed-%%~nxF"
```

**EDIT** The simplest solution to the problem of the infinite loop is to work in two stages:

1. prepare the list of operations
2. execute the plan.

-

```
set OpList=%TEMP%\%~n0%RANDOM%.bat
copy nul "%OpList%"
for %%F in (%~1\*) do echo ren "%%~F" "renamed-%%~nxF" >> "%OpList%"
call "%OpList%"
del "%OpList%"
```

Comment: That works well, except I want to rename the file by prepending the folder in front of it.  Ex: /Fall 2009/Notes.txt would become /Fall 2009/Fall 2009-Notes.txt  When I use: do ren "%%~F" "%~1-%%~nxF" it gets stuck in a loop if the folder name alphabetically comes before other files in the folder.  Ex: In a folder named "Tax Forms" with 2 files named "Fall 2009.pdf" and "Winter 2008.pdf", the Fall 2009 will get renamed "Tax Forms-Fall 2009", then "Tax Forms-Tax Forms-Fall 2009", etc. in an endless loop.  How can this be fixed?