# how to rename all file name which contain specific word to another word in a folder using bat or shell script

Tags: shell, batch-file

how to write a batch script or shell script to rename files in a folder

ie ..replace the name arun_XYZ to arun_ABC present in all file names (replace xyz to abc)

and how to also replace a word XYZ present inside  all files with the word ABC

Answer (score 1):

Shell:

To rename files:

```
for fname in *_XYZ; do
   newname=`echo "$fname" | sed 's/_XYZ/_ABC/g'`
   echo "$fname" "$newname"
done
```

After testing replace `echo $fname...` to `mv $fname...`.

To rename tiles and replace files content:

```
for fname in *_XYZ; do
   newname=`echo "$fname" | sed 's/_XYZ/_ABC/g'`
   sed 's/XYZ/ABC/g' "$fname" >"$newname"
done
```

Comment: i m not able to replace contents only file name got replaced

Comment: @Arunachalam it generates the file with the new name and the same content?

Comment: yes  it generates the file with the new name and the same content

Comment: @Arunachalam you may try to do `sed 's/XYZ/ABC/g' file >newfile` manually for one file to see what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

As this question has the "dos-batch" tag, I assume that Arunachalam needs a dos solution, not a bash one.

You asked two completly different questions.

1. For renaming filenames you could look at [batch-script-to-rename-files-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436186/batch-script-to-rename-files-in-folder-argument) or [how-to-change-file-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481349/how-to-change-file-extensions-of-multiple-files-on-a-directory-with-command)
2. For changing the file content you could read [Batch Substitute](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1516)